# Javascript script refers to all ids in document as undefined when called from Jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Jade file named index.jade which is as follows:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    img.ball(src="images/ball.png" width=20)
    br
    canvas.game-canvas(width=300 height=300)
    script(src="/javascripts/test.js")
```

My issue with this is that when the test.js is called through the script tag, getting any element from the document turns out to be undefined.

My short test.js is as follows:

```
for (var e in document.getElementsByTagName("*"))
    console.log(e.id);
```

When I load my page through localhost, the console spits this out:

[image]
Is there a workaround for this? How would I be able to get any element by id if it all turns out undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate through a node list. That will give you a bunch of numberical strings, since a node list is array-like and has numeric keys. A string has no `id` property. Try this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
    console.log(els[i].id);
```

Comment: I've tried doing this and although there is no undefined output as before, it just outputs blank strings.

Comment: @OrangeReceptacle Do you have any elements with `id`s? None of the ones you've shown in you jade file have one.